# Problems with Uniform Buffers in WebGL2

Tags: javascript, webgl, webgl2

I am trying to port some OpenGL code to WebGL2 and I have some problems with Uniform Buffers. Everything I render with the shader the buffer is attached to is no longer displayed. I get no errors or warnings in the console. This is my code:

```
var data = new Float32Array(1);
data[0] = 1.0;

var uniformBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, uniformBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, 4, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.bindBufferRange(gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, uniformBuffer, 0, 4);

gl.uniformBlockBinding(mapShader.getProgram(), gl.getUniformBlockIndex(mapShader.getProgram(), "test"), 0);


gl.bindBuffer(gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, uniformBuffer);
gl.bufferSubData(gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, data);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, null);
```

Once I add this to my shader the problems I described earlier appear:

```
layout (std140) uniform test {
    float testFloat;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next time please be kind and save us from having to manually make a repo! Thanks ‍♂️

When I run your code in Chrome I get

> :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: uniform buffers : buffer or buffer range at index 0 not large enough

The problem is there are padding and alignment issues

See [the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf) section 2.12.6.4

Changing your buffer and range size to 16 and it works. Also note there are alignment requirements for valid offsets to `BindBufferRange` you can look up with `gl.getParameter(gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER_OFFSET_ALIGNMENT)`

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl2');

const vs = `#version 300 es
void main() {
  gl_PointSize = 100.0;
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
`;

const fs = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;

layout (std140) uniform test {
    float testFloat;
};

out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
  outColor = vec4(testFloat, 0, 0, 1);
}
`;

const prg = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
gl.useProgram(prg);
const mapShader = {
  getProgram: _ => prg,
};

var data = new Float32Array(1);
data[0] = 1.0;

var uniformBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, uniformBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, 16, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.bindBufferRange(gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, uniformBuffer, 0, 16);

gl.uniformBlockBinding(mapShader.getProgram(), gl.getUniformBlockIndex(mapShader.getProgram(), "test"), 0);


gl.bindBuffer(gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, uniformBuffer);
gl.bufferSubData(gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, data);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, null);

gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>

<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, I tested it a bit and every additional float adds 4 to the size right?

Comment: floats are padded to a vec4 so 1 float is 16bytes, 2 floats is 16 bytes, 4 is 16 bytes, 5 is 32bytes. etc... The rules are spelled out in the spec linked in the answer.